# Proof through contradiction

Tags: logic

My textbook says: To prove $A\Rightarrow B$ we have to lead $A \wedge \neg B$ to a contradiction. Does it imply, that $B\Rightarrow A$ would also be true? As far as I know $\wedge$ is commutative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that $\wedge$ is commutative means that $A\wedge(\neg B)$ is logically equivalent to $(\neg B)\wedge A$.  But to prove $B\Rightarrow A$ by contradiction you would start by assuming $B\wedge(\neg A)$, which is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement $A \Rightarrow B$ is true when it is **not** the case that $A$ is true and $B$ is false. That is, the conditional is true when we have $\lnot (A \land \lnot B)$. That is why the textbook says

> To prove $A \Rightarrow B$ we have to lead $A \land \lnot B$ to a contradiction.

Here is the question:

> Does it imply, that $B \Rightarrow A$ would also be true? As far as I know $\land$ is commutative.

To see how the [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)), $B \Rightarrow A$, of the original conditional fits into this consider the following.

Using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), $\lnot (A \land \lnot B)$ is equivalent to $\lnot A \lor B$ which gives us the [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) rule of inference:

$$A \Rightarrow B \iff \lnot A \lor B$$

That the disjunction is commutative gives us the following:

$$\lnot A \lor B \iff B \lor \lnot A$$

That corresponds to the equivalence between the original conditional and its [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition):

$$A \Rightarrow B \iff \lnot B \Rightarrow \lnot A$$

However, $B \Rightarrow A$ is the converse, not the contrapositive, of the conditional $A \Rightarrow B$. If both the conditional and its converse are true then the [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_introduction), $A \iff B$, is true.  The contrapositive of the converse is called the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic)) of the original conditional:

$$B \Rightarrow A \iff \lnot A \Rightarrow \lnot B$$